# Why are indifference curves (often) of infinite length?

Tags: microeconomics, preferences

Indifference curves are often of infinite length.

Is this implied by monotonicity or non-satiation?

If not, what is/are some condition(s) that are sufficient for indifference curves to have infinite length?

---

More generally, indifference curves are almost always manifolds without boundary. Which means that the curves don't have endpoints. What property of the utility function guarentees this?

Comment: You could come up with utility function whose indifference curve is not infinite (e.g. $u(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$) and see what property it violates.

Comment: @Art How to prove the general case?

Comment: The point is you should have an idea first which property is required... then we can discuss proving :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the definition of indifference curve on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indifference_curve) then they can be of finite or infinite length. For example if you are completely indifferent between the two goods, the indiffernce curve would be of the form $x+y=const$ which is of finite length (in the positive quadrant).

A necessary criteria for infinite length would be that having $0$ of one good provides you with zero utility, so that any combination of a little bit of both has a higher utility than an arbitrary quantity of one good and zero of the other good.

**Edit in response to comment:** Indifference curves come in families, one can consider the family of indifference curves $x\cdot y = const.$, they satisfy the definition, are of infinite length and if either $x$ or $y$ is equal to zero, then the utility is equal to $0$ as well.

Comment: "A necessary criteria for infinite length would be that having $0$ of one good provides you with zero utility" -- I'm not sure if this is correct. Consider $U(x,y)=xy+1$ -- the indifference curves are of infinite length but it is not true that "having $0$ of one good provides you with zero utility".

Comment: But then the indifference curve at $u = 0$ would just be a point, not an infinitely long curve?

Comment: @Art No, the $0$ utility curve would correspond to all allocations where you have $0$ of one good, and some quantity of the other. So it is an infinitely long curve as well. It is just not smooth because it has a kink at the point where $x$ and $y$ both zero.